# creating and passing a checkbox array to javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, checkbox

I have an html form displaying a series of checkboxes. The checkboxes (an array called "checkbox" is ) are created using a loop in php. I want to use this array for some background processing. 
Trying to use AJAX as below, but I am not able to get it working.

Please help!

Here is test.php: containing html form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script language="javascript">
function activate(checkbox){

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        document.getElementById("ajaxState").innerHTML =xhttp.readyState;
        document.getElementById("ajaxStatus").innerHTML =xhttp.status;

        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("ajaxResponse").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "process.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(checkbox));
}
</script>

<html>
<body>
<form>
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    echo "$i: ";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[".$i."]'></input><br>";
}
?>

<button  type="button" name="button" onclick="activate(checkbox)" >Test</button>
</form>
<p>ajaxState: <span id="ajaxState"></span></p>
<p>ajaxStatus: <span id="ajaxStatus"></span></p>
<p>ajaxResponse: <span id="ajaxResponse"></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Output: Don't get any response.

process.php: decode json data and display the array

```
<?php 
$data = file_get_contents( "php://input" );
$checkbox = json_decode( $data, true ); 

echo "Hello!<br>";
var_dump($checkbox);
?>
```

NOTE: If, in the button element, I use this.checkbox, var_dump returns NULL.

```
<button  type="button" name="button" onclick="activate(this.checkbox)" >Test</button>
```

Response:
ajaxState: 4

ajaxStatus: 200

ajaxResponse: Hello!
NULL

Comment: What is not working ? Can you send valid data over php service ? What is `checkbox` argument ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script language="javascript">
function activate(){

    /*getting all inputs*/
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var cbs = []; //will contain all checkboxes
    var checked = []; //will contain all checked checkboxes
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
        cbs.push(inputs[i]);
        if (inputs[i].checked) {
          checked.push(inputs[i]);
        }
      }
    }

    //then making a request
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        document.getElementById("ajaxState").innerHTML =xhttp.readyState;
        document.getElementById("ajaxStatus").innerHTML =xhttp.status;

        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("ajaxResponse").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    console.log(xhttp);
    xhttp.open("POST", "process.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(checked));//sending checked instead of checkbox
}
</script>

<html>
<body>
<form>
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    echo "$i: ";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[".$i."]'></input><br>";
}
?>

<button  type="button" name="button" onclick="activate()" >Test</button>
</form>
<p>ajaxState: <span id="ajaxState"></span></p>
<p>ajaxStatus: <span id="ajaxStatus"></span></p>
<p>ajaxResponse: <span id="ajaxResponse"></span></p>


</body>
</html>
```

used [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/120677/HTML-CSS-JavaScript/find-Checkboxes) to get all checkboxes

Comment: This worked! Reading the inputs correctly in the javascript is what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Better use Query  see [jQuery - AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)
Here realization "Click on button and show id current button in ajax, for use in second needed tasks". If I right anderstand you.

```
{{--include jQuery CDN Library--}}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button  type="button" name="1" id="test" >Test</button>
<button  type="button" name="2" id="test" >Test</button>
<button  type="button" name="3" id="test" >Test</button>
...

<style>   
 $("button#test").change(function(){
var id = $(this).attr('name');
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url:    'process.php',
        data:   {id: id}
    })
        .done(function(msg){
            console.log('button: ' + msg);
        });
});    
</style>
```

And php file

```
<?php 
$data = $_POST['id']
$checkbox = json_encode($data); 

echo "Hello!<br>";
echo $data; // show id checkbox
?>
```

It is simpler realization codes, from same javascript codes